# use Redis client instance in other modules in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, commonjs

I have the following module which connects to a Redis database, and I want to get the client instance so I can call it from other modules without creating a new instance each time, I did the following:

```
let client;

const setClient = ({ redis, config }) => {
    client = redis.createClient({
        host: config.redis.host,
        port: config.redis.port
    });
};

const getClient = () => {
    return client;
};

const connect = ({ redis, config, logger }) => {
    setClient({ redis, config });
    client.on('connect', () => {
        logger.info(`Redis connected on port: ${client?.options?.port}`);
    });
    client.on('error', err => {
        logger.error(`500 - Could not connect to Redis: ${err}`);
    });
};

module.exports = { connect, client: getClient() };
```

when i call the client from other modules using `const { client } = require('./cache');` it gives me `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the following solution:

```
const cacheClient = () => {
    return {
        client: undefined,
        setClient({ redis, config }) {
            client = redis.createClient({
                host: config.redis.host,
                port: config.redis.port
            });
        },

        getClient() {
            return client;
        },

        connect({ redis, config, logger }) {
            this.setClient({ redis, config });
            client.on('connect', () => {
                logger.info(`Redis connected on port: ${client?.options?.port}`);
            });
            client.on('error', err => {
                logger.error(`500 - Could not connect to Redis: ${err}`);
            });
        }
    };
};

module.exports = cacheClient;
```

If there's a better approach please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

erase letClient() from top(the let) and on the bottom add const client = getClient() and on module exports just go with client instead of client: getClient()

Comment: Cannot access 'client' before initialization.  
Please can you provide a code snippet?